# Update Facebook object via API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to update a Facebook object such as page's album from the GRAPH API.

In my instance I would like to update the name and description of the album.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Facebook docs for the album endpoint](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/), there is no way to update any of the fields for the album.

Based on my experience, it's not possible to update *fields* for graph API objects.  Sometimes you can update *connections*, such as being able to [change the position of a tag for a particular user in a photo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/).